# POSTGRESQL: multiple condition with not exists in one table join

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have condition in `sql select` i want select the data from the table when `checktime >= date and checktime <= date` but not exists in same table when `the condition is checktime >= date and checktime <= date`

its my data from the table when its present `Y-m-d 06:15:00 until Y-m-d 07:45:00`:

```
 userid             name   checktime
195807311982032005  re1   2017-12-28 07:13:02
196001132006041007  re2   2017-12-28 07:14:37
196004201992031005  op6   2017-12-28 06:53:08
196005011986032014  re3   2017-12-28 07:01:24
196007311985032006  re4   2017-12-28 07:01:23
```

and then data from the table when its late`Y-m-d 07:45:00 until Y-m-d 23:45:00`:

```
userid              name   checktime
195807311982032005  re1   2017-12-28 07:55:02
196001132006041007  re2   2017-12-28 09:14:37
196004201992031005  op6   2017-12-28 10:53:08
```

> there's found same data in present and late time (name op6)

example and `this my query to show late person`:

```
select distinct on (co.userid) co.userid, ui.name
from checkinout co join
     userinfo ui
     on ui.userid = co.userid
where co.checktime >= '2017-12-28 07:45:00' and
      co.checktime <= '2017-12-28 13:45:00' AND NOT EXISTS 
(SELECT co.userid from checkinout WHERE co.checktime >= '2017-12-28 06:15:00' 
and co.checktime <='2017-12-28 07:45:00');
```

when i run its null but i just want `show all data in checkinout table` in some condition `but it's not showing again in present query` (*select in bracket*)

Comment: I think sample data and desired results would help.  Your conditions are the same, so the question doesn't make sense.

Comment: yeah i finished editing my post please help me @GordonLinoff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your result is null because you are contradicting yourself in the where statement.
If you are joining co.userid matching a checktime range that is inside the NOT EXISTS checktime range it means that it exists.

You are looking for users that check-in that check-in-out in this range

```
WHERE co.checktime >= '2017-12-28 06:15:00' and co.checktime <= '2017-12-28 07:45:00'
```

And the previous time range is included in the select that it's evaluated in NOT EXISTS function. In consequence those userId will always exist.

```
WHERE co.checktime > '2017-12-28 06:15:00' and co.checktime <='2017-12-28 23:15:00'
```

So running

```
NOT EXISTS (SELECT co.userid from checkinout WHERE co.checktime > '2017-12-28 06:15:00' and co.checktime <='2017-12-28 23:15:00');
```

In the last "and" will always be false and bring no results to your select.

Hope this helps and I understood you problem!

Comment: yah i know but i have some user checktime twice in a day and the checktime range when its present and late its display the same user. and i dont know how to display just one user in one day

Comment: Do you have a checktime id in the checkinout table? Maybe you can compare different checktime id in order to see the ones you are missing.

Comment: there isnt checktime id just id from checkinout table and the id auto_increment when the user its use fingerprint

Comment: I see that you modified the question. You want to print the op6 name? Or re1 & re2. You modify your not exist select to check the co.id <> co2.id. Tell me what it should be your result of the query with that example in order to pass you the solution.

Comment: no i want to show data where the condition in first condition and where the data in second condition in not exists subquery its not exits. in first query name op6 its show and in second query its show again because i just want to show late person when the person it's not in first condition

Comment: or do you have any idea or example to show present and late person where if the user tab twice in one day and in other condition time it's just show one data in query

Answer (score 0):

The logic you express is of this form:

```
select co.userid, ui.name
from checkinout co join
     userinfo ui
     on ui.userid = co.userid
group by 
from ch
having sum( (co.checktime >= '2017-12-28 06:15:00' and
             co.checktime <= '2017-12-28 07:45:00'
            )::int ) > 0 and
       sum( (co.checktime >  '2017-12-28 06:15:00' and
             co.checktime <= '2017-12-28 23:15:00'
            )::int) = 0;
```

However, the dates don't really look right on the conditions.